# Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null (even bool variable assigned to true/false)

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart

I have made this app `WorldTime` app in `Dart Flutter` and I am getting a repeated unexplianed error `Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null`, I tried to search for this error all I got is bool variable must be assigned to `true` or `false`. So here is a piece of code in which I have a bool variable which I tried to make it equal to false/true but it still gave me the error.
The code which has bool variable:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class WorldTime {
  String location;
  String time;
  String flag;
  String url;
  bool isMorning ;

  WorldTime({this.location, this.flag, this.url});

  Future<void> getTime() async {
    try {
      Response response =
          await get(Uri.https('worldtimeapi.org', 'api/timezone/$url'));
      Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

      String datetime = data['datetime'];
      String offset = data['utc_offset'].substring(0, 3);
      String offset_mnt = data['utc_offset'].substring(4, 6);

      DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
      now = now.add(
          Duration(hours: int.parse(offset), minutes: int.parse(offset_mnt)));

      isMorning = now.hour > 6 && now.hour < 20 ? true : false;

      time = DateFormat.jm().format(now);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error occured: $e");
      time = "Cannot Display Time Due to Error Occured";
    }
  }
}
```

The full code link and files are on my GitHub Repository
`Link:` [WorldTimeApp](https://github.com/TheHarshKadam/World_Time)

Also my app needs `active internet connection` so I assured that I have active internet to fetch details from API still getting the same error

Any help will be much appreciated:)

Comment: Not sure if that it the problem but you are never initialize `isMorning` with any value. Since you are using `bool` as type, this is a problem since it would end up with the value `null` which is not allowed.

Comment: @julemand101 I tried to assign `isMorning = true/false` but same error occured :(

Comment: Inside home.dart you have `String bgImg = data['isMorning'] ? 'Day.jpeg' : 'Night.jpeg';` but I don't see that `"isMorning"` is being added to `data` when starting your application. This is first being done later in home.dart inside the creation of `Scaffold`. So `data['isMorning']` is properly returning `null`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, your api call might have failed, as a result your boolean flag (isMorning) is never initialized. possible fixes

- Try initializing the variable before making the api call
- Try setting either true or false to isMorning flag in catch block
- or Try checking for null, then do boolean check. for eg.,

  ```
   bool _isMorning = data['isMorning'] != null && data['isMorning'] != false;
   String bgImg = _isMorning ? 'Day.jpeg' : 'Night.jpeg';
   Color colors = _isMorning ? Colors.blue[50] : Colors.blueGrey[800];
  ```